# Regex in htaccess not working on server

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have the following regex in the .htaccess file, its working fine in my local machine, but on the **server localhost** this will not work If I have the `\/` in the regular expression

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^orders\/ order.php [L]
```

My url will looks like `localhost/items/orders/casio-watch`.

*Here `items` is the foldername

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Your rewrite rule is expecting a URL that **^** (starts with) `orders`, but your URL starts whith `items`.

Comment: @azeós but items is a folder inside localhost

Comment: @AnandSolanki Please stop this sort of childish edits. I guess you do it in order to obtain 2 rep points. I've rolled it back

Comment: But what are you rewriting? What should happen with `casio-watch`? Try `^items\/orders\/` and see what happen.

Comment: @hek2mgl. Pl check my edits. These are not meaning less. I also give answers and most points are based on those. So you don't worry and do your own business my friend.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What should `localhost/items/orders/casio-watch` be rewritten to?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RewriteBase` statement in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /items
```